# In Calc, can I populate a cell with a code related to another cell?

Tags: excel, populate, calc

A simple question:

In Libre Office / Calc, I need to populate a cell with code related to what I enter into another cell. Example:
If I type "Ice Cream" in cell A1, I need Calc to automatically enter "Syrup" in cell A2; similarly, if I type "Hot Dog" in cell A1, I need Calc to automatically type "Ketchup" in cell A2.

I just can not do it.

In fact, I need this for a series of 3-letter codes (such as abbreviations) for products. Whatever function may be used, if any, it must include at least 20 different products (and their 20 codes).

Any chance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what `VLOOKUP` is for.

Make a table of all abbreviations and products:

```
CAR    Carrots
CEL    Celeri
TOM    Tomatoes
...
```

(I put mine in `F2:G21`)

Then use the following formula in `B2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,F$2:G$21,2)
```

And populate down